# Xcode Copied Project Not Working

Tags: xcode5, cocos2d-x, tapjoy

I had a working project and then I copied project to other directory but it didn't work.

Now I have made a new xcode project and added all the required folders and files. It is compiling fine but give this error

> > Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'TJCLoadingView''

I am using Xcode5. Please tell me what is the issue as I am new to xcode.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a file called TJCLoadingView.xib?  If so, is it mentioned in the "Copy Bundle Resources" part of your target's "Build Phases" tab?  (If you don't have that file, that is a likely source of the problem itself.)

Comment: Sounds like you either did not copy the entire project, or you created or added a file (TCJLoadingView) outside of that project's folder tree. Is that file perhaps listed in red in Xcode? If so, it's missing.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly the same problem for me. For me adding the bundle `TapjoyResources.bundle` to `Copy Bundle Resources` under `Build Phases` helped. It is included in the `Tapjoy.framework` file.

I guess it was not copied straight away but maybe it should have if you include the framework correctly from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem.
I do not know what went wrong , but it helped me.

Follow this steps:

1. Remove all TapJoy files from the project.
2. Download latest version from the site (now it's 9.1.4)
3. Add it to the project exactly like on [Getting Started Page](https://knowledge.tapjoy.com/en/integration/getting-started-guide-for-publishers#ios) (through Drag'n'Drop) - at first I try to add by usual way and get exception like yours!
4. Add all of those libs:

   - AdSupport
   - CFNetwork
   - CoreGraphics
   - CoreLocation
   - CoreMotion
   - CoreTelephony
   - EvenKitUI
   - EventKit
   - Foundation
   - libsqlite3.0
   - libxml2
   - libz
   - MapKit
   - MediaPlayer
   - MessageUI
   - MobileCoreServices
   - QuartzCore
   - Social (Optional)
   - StoreKit
   - SystemConfiguration
   - Twitter
   - UIKit
5. Add your TJ something code like :

   [Tapjoy requestTapjoyConnect:kTapJoyAppID
                          secretKey:kTapJoySecretKey
                            options:@{ TJC_OPTION_ENABLE_LOGGING : @(YES) }
       ];
6. Try to compile again.